Residual index / partial covariance interpretation in linear regression
(START EDIT) to address EdM's comment for clarification.  I do not have a specific relationship I want to measure or study.  Instead, a paper I am reading already used the regression of (residuals of G ~ B) ~ D.  I am trying to interpret their results for myself, but I am having trouble.  In the real dataset I am studying, we only have observations of variables B, D, and G.  We do not know C and the relationship between B and D could be established by some other mechanism like maybe maybe B causes C causes D is the actual connection. (END EDIT)
I am simulating data according to the following model

where my final outcome variable is a bird species' average brain mass.
I need help interpreting the beta coefficient fitted from the following OLS regression
$$
(residuals~of~G \thicksim B) \thicksim D
$$
which gives the fitted line of best fit of
$$
(residuals~of~G \thicksim B) = \alpha + \beta D
$$
I have closed form solutions for beta in terms of the partial covariance, the partial correlation, and correlations which I think make its value particularly clear.  All that said, I would like to interpret $\beta$ as telling me about how G itself changes given some conditions rather than how residuals of G on B change.  Is that possible?  I am happy to reimagine the system a bit if it gives a nicer interpretation.  For example, I could flip either the B2 or B3 arrows so one of B/D directly causes the other.  Any further insight on what exactly $\beta$ is telling me would be appreciated.  Below are my three closed form expressions for the value of $\beta$ which are still leaving me confused.
$$
\beta = \frac{partial~covariance~of(G,D |B)}{var(D)}
$$
where the partial covariance of (G,D |B) is
$$
partial~covariance~of(G,D |B) = cov(G,D) - \frac{cov(G,B)cov(B,D)}{var(B)}
$$
Also, $\beta$ can be expressed in terms of the partial correlation
$$
\beta = \rho_{GD\cdot B}\frac{sd(residuals~of~G \thicksim B )sd(residuals~of~D \thicksim B)}{var(D)}
$$
Finally, my favorite expression is this next one because it shows $\beta$ is the correlation betweeen G and D that is not traceable through B standardized to the correct units for the regression
$$
\beta = \big(cor(G,D) - cor(G,B)cor(B,D)\big)\frac{sd(G)}{sd(D)}
$$
However I am still confused.  How in my simulated dataset could I change D by one unit and control for the effects of changing B so that my G actually increases by $\beta$.  If possible I would like to interpret $\beta$ in terms of the original model rather than the residuals, because at least to me, the residuals do not really mean anything, as far as I can tell the residuals of G ~ B are some type of estimate of E-A or something, but it's confusing.
Any perspectives/opinions welcome. thank you.

Please edit the question to clarify what you are trying to understand scientifically with your combination of simulation and OLS modeling. If you simulate you presumably know all the associations already. Why should residuals be associated with D; doesn't the G~B model incorporate D via B6? There might be a more direct way to accomplish your scientific goal without trying to interpret partial correlations, but you would have to provide more information about the substance of your project. Please do that by editing the question; comments are often overlooked and can be deleted.

I don't know if the residuals should be associated with D via B6, I suppose that is part of my question.  I edited it the question.  I am happy to further edit it, please let me know. :)

Could you please provide a reference and link to the paper you are reading that you are trying to interpret?

http://webhome.auburn.edu/~tds0009/Articles/Freckleton%202002.pdf
The article is about how the (residuals of G ~ B) ~ D regression is a biased estimate of the B6 value, but I think I have shown with my formulas that it is not that, but instead an unbiased estimate of ... well, I'm not exactly sure, but I guess if you agree with the article that the interpretation of it is pure nonsense, that is fine, I will believe what you say.  I just don't believe the author since their argument seems to be: it does not estimate B6, therefore it is wrong and useless.

The paper you cite describes the best practice. I recall being taught (many decades ago) about how you might use serial regressions of residuals as a way to think about multiple regression, but that only works if the predictors are completely uncorrelated (as that paper explains) and it isn't standard practice.
If you want to evaluate the associations of B and D with G, you should perform a multiple regression, possibly including an interaction between B and D, B:D, to allow for the association of one with G to depend on the value of the other. For example, if you are modeling ln(G) as the outcome in R:
lm(ln(G) ~ B + D + B:D)

If B and D are continuous you should consider modeling them flexibly, for example with a regression spline, as the strictly linear associations implicit in the above formula aren't often the case. Then you can use that model to "interpret $\beta$ in terms of the original model rather than the residuals."
In your simulations it's possible that there is so little correlation between B and D that there isn't appreciable bias. You can see that in your last equation if $\text{cor}(B,D) \approx 0$. The regressions with residuals can't be counted on to work in general, however, and they just complicate things beyond what you would find with a straightforward, standard multiple regression model.
